# input dialog not return value in android

Tags: android, android-dialog

hello i want to return something from android alert dialog box here is the code

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(c);
    builder.setTitle("User's Input");
    builder.setMessage(msg);
    final EditText input = new EditText(c);
    input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS);
    builder.setView(input);
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            text=input.getText().toString();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //dialog.cancel();
            c.finish();
        }
    });

    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.show();
    return text;
```

but when i call this method like this..

```
String email=MyMethods.showTextDialog(this,"Enter Recovery Email:");
    if(email=="")
        this.finish();
```

the if() statement executes before i press any button in dialog box... i want to execute code after dialog box button click .. please help me

Comment: when do you want to show the dialog...                                                       String email=MyMethods.showTextDialog(this,"Enter Recovery Email:");                 this is not the correct way to call dialog

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-prompt-user-input-dialog-example/

Answer (score 0):

```
Create a method like this :

public Dialog showDialog(String title, String msg, final Activity activity) {

        final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
                .create();
        alertDialog.setTitle(title);
        alertDialog.setMessage(msg);
        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                alertDialog.dismiss();

                    activity.finish();

            }
        });
        alertDialog.show();

        return alertDialog;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute code after dialog box button click... then try like below...

Put your code in onClick event of dialog...

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(c);
    builder.setTitle("User's Input");
    builder.setMessage(msg);
    final EditText input = new EditText(c);
    input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS);
    builder.setView(input);
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            text=input.getText().toString();

            // put your code here                   
            if(text.equals(""))
                  this.finish();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //dialog.cancel();
            c.finish();
        }
    });

    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the dialog in  button click or evrn on click of the edit text and then show the dialog like this

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {


                LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                View dialog= li.inflate(R.layout.dialog_view, null);

                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        context);


                alertDialogBuilder.setView(dialog);

                final EditText value= (EditText) dialog
                        .findViewById(R.id.value);


                alertDialogBuilder
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("OK",
                      new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {


                        edittext.setText(value.getText());
                        }
                      })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                      new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                        }
                      });


                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();


                alertDialog.show();

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

alert.setTitle("Title");
alert.setMessage("Message");

// Set an EditText view to get user input 
final EditText input = new EditText(this);
alert.setView(input);

alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
  String value = input.getText();
  // Do something with value!
  }
});

alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
    // Canceled.
  }
});

alert.show();
```

Source : http://www.androidsnippets.com/prompt-user-input-with-an-alertdialog